# Enter in my application when i click on the notification in the notifications bar

Tags: onclick, android-preferences, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

In my application the user can decide if show the notifications or not through a preferences screen. Well the notification works but i would that clicking on the notification i would be able to enter in my application. This is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void checkPref(Intent intent){ 
            this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this); 
            boolean pref_opt1 = myPref.getBoolean("firstDependent", false); 
            int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
            if (pref_opt1){
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                 .setContentTitle("Battery Informations")
                 .setContentText("Battery level"+" "+level+"%")
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not)
                 //.setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
                 .setTicker(level+"%")
                 .build();

                 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
                 PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);
                 notifi.notify(215,notification);
                } else {
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notifi.cancel(215);
                }
        }
```

I thought the PendingIntent did this function but nothing happen. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the pending intent to the Notification using [`setContentIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).

See also the documentation for [`Notification.contentIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent); in particular note that you'll need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the Intent, and also make sure that your MainActivity is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` so the notification manager (actually, the System UI) can see it.